# UILongPressGestureRecognizer giving weird results

Tags: iphone, ipad, gesture-recognition

i am developing a app in which i am applying UILongPressGesture recognizer on a view,and implemented code to be implemented for the event(long press gesture when occured).

the code for handling the gesture is written in a method and the method is called twice when i attempted to long press the view which is undesired. i have assigned a minimum time of 2 seconds. i am not sure that i am pressing the view for exactly 2 seconds. will the method get called after the 2 seconds time elaps?

can someone help me in this regard and how to handle situation when user long presses for more than the min time assigned, or is there any other reason for the method being called twice?

tnx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The handler is getting called twice for the gesture recognizer states `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` and `UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized`. You will probably want to deal with a `UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized`. So do this in the handler,

```
- (void)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    if ( gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized ) {
        // Handle long press.
    }
}
```

Comment: tnx for the reply deepak, i resolved the above issue in a different way.i tried ur approach but it didn't work for me. anyway tnx for the reply......